# How to access language resource file values in code behind

Tags: asp.net, resources, globalization, resx

I can access language resource file values in mark up fine using below code:

```
<%=Resources.MainResource.MyKey%>
```

But I cannot do the same in code behind. Shouldn't it just be as follows:

```
Dim MyValue = Resources.MainResource.MyKey
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done the following:

- Added an App_GlobalResources Folder to my project
- Added to this folder a Resource file with the Name "Resource1"
- Then I created a *Key* with the name "String1" and the value = "hi" in this resource file
- In codebehind I did the following to take this key's value and initialize some variable with this value

c#

```
string s = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource1", "String1");
lit.Text = s;
```

And it works. It showed me "hi" for the label on my ASP.NET page.